# CartoDB multiple sublayers toggle?

Tags: carto

CartoDB LayerActions Toggle

Is there a way to make one button that shows a sublayer on one click, then hides on the next click. So one button per sublayer which turns the layer on and turns the layer off. Similar to the functionality built into the CartoDB UI.

For example how could I reprogram a toggle button by using some other piece of code, or could I expand the function in the HTML file by using a flag value (0 for an ON state which could be show(), and another value such as 1 for an OFF state which would be hide())

This is my code below:

```
<!--
Created using JS Bin
http://jsbin.com

Copyright (c) 2014 by anonymous (http://jsbin.com/bucupoga/2/edit)

Released under the MIT license: http://jsbin.mit-license.org
-->
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/themes   /css/cartodb.css" />
<script src="http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/cartodb.js"></script>
<style>
html, body {width:100%; height:100%; padding: 0; margin: 0;}
#cartodb-map { width: 100%; height:100%; background: black;}
#menu { position: absolute; top: 5px; right: 10px; width: 400px;       height:60px; background: transparent; z-index:10;}
#menu a { 
  margin: 15px 10px 0 0;
  float: right;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  width: 70px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font: bold 11px "Helvetica",Arial;
  line-height: normal;
  color: #555;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #777777;
  background: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#menu a.selected,
#menu a:hover { 
  color: #F84F40;
}

</style>

<script>
var map;
function init(){
  // initiate leaflet map
  map = new L.Map('cartodb-map', { 
    center: [30,-70],
    zoom: 4
  })

  var layerUrl = 'http://tdf.cartodb.com/api/v2/viz/96a73a9a-11dc-11e4-9973-0e73339ffa50/viz.json';


  var sublayers = [];


  cartodb.createLayer(map, layerUrl)
.addTo(map)
.on('done', function(layer) {
    var subLayerOptions = {
  sql: "SELECT * FROM nh_20growth_20strategy_map_20input",
    }

    var sublayer = layer.getSubLayer(0);

    sublayer.set(subLayerOptions);

    sublayers.push(sublayer);
    }).on('error', function() {
  //log the error
});



var LayerActions = {
novant: function(){
  sublayers[0].setSQL("SELECT * FROM nh_20growth_20strategy_map_20input WHERE system = 'Novant Health'");
  return true;
},
  all: function(){
  sublayers[0].setSQL("SELECT * FROM nh_20growth_20strategy_map_20input");
  return true;
}
}

$('.button').click(function() {
$('.button').removeClass('selected');
$(this).addClass('selected');
LayerActions[$(this).attr('id')]();
});
}


</script>


</head>
<body onload="init()">
<div id='cartodb-map'></div>
<div id='menu'>
<a href="#novant" id="novant" class="button novant">Novant Health</a>
<a href="#all" id="all" class="button all">All</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```